# Android: Thread Runnable and Handler.post issues - (Handler.postXX does not run on time when expected) within the Run method

Tags: java, android

I have a TCP Socket used as a TCP client which is used to read incoming data from a server **constantly** -- until the client or the server drops the connection. I don't know of any other way but use a **while (true)** loop in a different Runnable thread and in it (in the while loop) check for incoming data. The received data needs to be printed in an **EditText**.

The problem I am having is updating the text from **Handler.post(...)**.

I know that:

- In order to create TCP connections with Android 3.0 and above, I am required to place the TCP code either in a **new Thread(...)** or an **AsyncTask** because Strict mode has been enabled by default and I do not want to disable it.
- I know that in order to update the UI from a new Thread in Android, I need to use Handler.post() if I use a **Thread** or the **onProgressUpdate** via **publichProgress** if I use **AsyncTask** and I know how to use all these but I am experiencing *weird* frustrating issues with both of them.

So, all I want to do is:

- Listen to the server permanently
- As soon as the server sends me a message, example: 'w' or 'a' or n', I immidiately display it on the EditText. You can think of it as a telnet session but I need "more" 
  precision than telnet as I want to process every single byte, even non-printable ones so I do **not** want to use **readLine** in anyway. I **must** read a byte at a time OR get a buffer of bytes and then process them separately by iterating through the buffer. I went with a byte at a time.

Here is the code I have and please **pay attention to my comment above handle.response** to see the problem I am having. I hope you can clear this out.

The code is very briefly coded and I have removed a lot of the error checking sections for this sample.

I have a new class called: ThreadClientInput:

```
public class ThreadClientInput  implements Runnable {

InputStream inputStream;
MainActivity mainActivity;
Handler handler = new Handler();
int NextByte = 0;

public ThreadClientInput(MainActivity ma)
{
    mainActivity = ma;
}

@Override
public void run() 
{ 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Run the sensitive code that requires us to create this thread
    try {
        mainActivity.tcp_Client = new Socket("192.168.1.90", 23);
    }
    catch (Exception e){Log.e("EXEPTION:", e.getMessage().toString());return;}
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    // Only try to get the inputStream if we have a successful connection
    if (mainActivity.tcp_Client != null) 
    {
        try 
        {
            inputStream = mainActivity.tcp_Client.getInputStream();
        }
        catch (Exception e){Log.e("EXEPTION:", e.getMessage().toString()); return;}
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Update the text on the "Connect" button
    handler.post(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        { mainActivity.btn_Connect.setText("Connected");}
    });
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////

    try 
    {   

        // I need to constantly read the data until we manually disconnect or
        // the server drops the connection
        while (true) 
        {
            // Get the next byte
            // I do not want to use "readline()" from a BufferedReader etc because I need to know exactly what's coming in
            // I need to process every single byte
            NextByte = inputStream.read();

            if (NextByte > -1)
            {
                Log.e("in (While loop):", Character.toString((char)NextByte));

                *** Here is the problem ****
                // Update the EditText and this is where the problem starts
                // if the server sends "1234", the Log.e() above will display everything correctly: "1234"
                // however the handler.post below will run at the end of the last byte so the
                // the EditText as well as the second Log.e below within the handle.post will display: "1444" or "4444" or "2444"
                // So the handler.post does *not* run immediately even if I try handle.postAtFrontOfQueue()
                // If the server sends "12345678", again, Log.e() above will display everything correctly: "12345678" 
                // however the handler.post below will run at the end of the last byte again
                // and I will get "88888888" (most of the time) or "18888888" 

                //   

                handler.post(new Runnable() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        mainActivity.et_Response.setText(mainActivity.et_Response.getText() + Character.toString((char)NextByte));
                        Log.e("In handler.post:", Character.toString((char)NextByte));
                    }
                });
            }
        }           
    }
    catch (Exception e){Log.e("EXEPTION:", e.getMessage().toString());}
}}
```

I tried various variations including one with **runOnUiThread** and AsyncTask, with all I am getting same results. I am out, I have nothing. At this point of time I am just reading some documentation about Handle.post method to see if I can make sense.

I hope you have a solution and I know that "**while (true)**" isn't a good practice but I can break the loop from outside the thread with setting a flag and I don't know of any other way how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are able to access `NextByte` from `public void run()` without defining it as final !?

- If you want the handler to post message to the Activity UI thread, yo should create it **within** the activity class so it can access its Looper.

I can think of two solutions for your problem as follows:

1- To use a custom Runnable class where you pass to it the NextByte value as variable e.g.

```
   handler.post(new MyRunnable(NextByte));
```

And MyRunnable can be something like:

```
  class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
   int byteData;  
   public MyRunnable(int byteData){
      this.byteData = byteData;
   }

     public void run(){ // update the EditText}
  }
```

2- To use handler.sendMessage(); and add the NextByte as the message argument e.g.

```
 Message msg = new Message();
 msg.arg1 = NextBye
 handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

And your handler should be defined as following:

```
handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            int nextByte = msg.arg1;
                            // update the EditText
        }
    };
```

Comment: As far as solution number 1 goes, it did not work. I get the same output. I created a method in MainActivity.java called updateText(int b) and within it, I have the handler.post that updates the text. I call this method immediately after NextByte = inputStream.read(); but I got the same output.

Comment: For solution number 2, I am not familiar with the Handler.sendMessage concept, for some reason it's worse, if I send "12345678" from the server, I will like get "123" and it stops...no thrown exceptions.

Comment: I do not think your changes reflect the solutions I suggested earlier. For solution 1, you need to create *a new* runnable object and pass to it the NextByte with *every* handler.post(). Also, The handler should be defined and initialized in the MainActivity class

Comment: It works!! Thank you!! :D :D :D Yes, obviously I have misunderstood you the first time but your second post is crystal clear!! Thx! Have a look my crazy work around above but now that crazy workaround will be scrapped as I do not want to use it.

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted so if anyone has similar problem can directly find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been resolved.

This is what I did this.

In MainActivity.java which is the main file, in class MainActivity

```
    public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    int currentByte = 0;

    public MyRunnable(int b){
        currentByte = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        mainActivity.et_Response.setText(mainActivity.et_Response.getText() + Character.toString((char)currentByte));
    }
}
```

I have a statement **mainActivity = this;** in **onCreate** and then in **ThreadClientInput.run**

```
        try {
        while (true)
        {
            NextByte = inputStream.read(); 

            // if the server drops the connection, break out the loop
            if (NextByte < 0) break;

            handler.post(new MainActivity.MyRunnable(NextByte));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("EXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
    }
```

After this, handler.post is getting called correctly and at the correct and expected time. Full credit goes to iTech.